# How can i get the item to count in span?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show the numbers of total what showing in the string htmlresult in Span class. I dont get it to work. Please help.

```
 var htmlResult = '<a href="#popupBasic" id="popupBasicLink" data-close- 
 btn="right" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner- 
 all ui-shadow ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left" data- 
 transition="pop">Trafikmeddelanden<span class="ui-li-count" id="count"> 
 </span></a>';

htmlResult = htmlResult + '<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">';

var reasoncode = item.ReasonCodeText;

matched = item.ReasonCodeText
$("count").html(matched.length);

htmlResult = htmlResult   + reasonCodeText.toUpperCase().bold() + '</b> 
<p>Starttid: ' + outputDate + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + 
' - Uppdaterad: ' + outputDate2 + ' ' + hours2 + ':' + minutes2 + 
'<br />' + externalDescription + '</p>';
```

The `item.ReasonCodeText` is from the Swedish *trafikverkets* API to get traffic announcement for train. The `item.ReasonCodeText` can include several items. I want to get all items to be counted.

Comment: `$("count").html(matched.length);` Needs to be `$("#count").html(matched.length);` `#` indicates it's an ID.

Comment: It dosent work. The square is still empty. enter image description here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDmCA.png

Comment: What does matched.length return?

Comment: I returns nothing in the square. I know that in this it should be shown seven events from the station in attached picture. This is like headline of Possible cause of the event.

Comment: That didn’t answer my question. If you do console.log(matched.length) what does it return?

Comment: That doses not return nothing.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You need to work backwards from there to figure out why it's not returning anything. Start with `console.log(matched)` and keep moving up the code until you figure out what is broken.

Comment: I dont get it to work. Is there possible to count all the <p> instead to be showing in span count?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But i have manage to fix, Thanks for your help.