# Need help to count paragraphs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need some help to count the numbers of `<p>` paragraphs. And the the number I want to be shown in the span class down in the code. I want to show the numbers of the announcements. The items is from Swedish Trafikverket open API

I have been trying this without succes
[How can i get the item to count in span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008690/how-can-i-get-the-item-to-count-in-span)

```js
var htmlResult = '<a href="#popupBasic" id="popupBasicLink" data-close-btn="right" data-position="fixed" data-role="collapsible" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left" data-transition="slidedown"><font color="#0040ff">Trafikmeddelanden<span id "test" class="ui-li-count" ></span></font></a>';

htmlResult = htmlResult + '<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">';


$(announcement).each(function(iterator, item) {
  var startDateTime = new Date(item.StartDateTime);
  var hours = startDateTime.getHours();
  var minutes = startDateTime.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

  var month = startDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = startDateTime.getDate();

  var outputDate = startDateTime.getFullYear() + '-' +
    (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

  var lastUpdateDateTime = new Date(item.LastUpdateDateTime);
  var hours2 = lastUpdateDateTime.getHours();
  var minutes2 = lastUpdateDateTime.getMinutes();
  if (minutes2 < 10) minutes2 = "0" + minutes2;

  var month2 = lastUpdateDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
  var day2 = lastUpdateDateTime.getDate();
  var outputDate2 = lastUpdateDateTime.getFullYear() + '-' +
    (month2 < 10 ? '0' : '') + month2 + '-' +
    (day2 < 10 ? '0' : '') + day2;

  var externalDescription = item.ExternalDescription;
  var reasonCodeText = item.ReasonCodeText;

  var countyNo = item.CountyNo;


  htmlResult = htmlResult + reasonCodeText.toUpperCase().bold() + '</b><p>Starttid: ' + outputDate + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes +
    ' - Uppdaterad: ' + outputDate2 + ' ' + hours2 + ':' + minutes2 +
    '<br />' + externalDescription + '</p>';


});



htmlResult = htmlResult + '</div>';



$('#staionInfoMessageDiv').html(htmlResult);
/*
$('#popupBasic').popup();
$('#popupBasic').popup("close");
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="staionInfoMessageDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and HTML to make it a [mcve] I commented out the last lines so when the code works you can update that